# Registration Authority (RA) and Validation Authority (VA) Certificate

Tags: ssl, certificate, x509certificate, pki

Can any one explain where can I find `Registration Authority (RA)` and `Validation Authority (VA)` of a website such as [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/) in `Browser` like `Google Chrome`? also how can I document the `X.509` record ?

Answer (score 0):

The Registration Authority (RA) certificate will not necessarily be visible to you as the relying party.  When a website such as Wikipedia enrols for a certificate *they* will approach a CA to request a certificate.  That process normally happens through a Registration Authority and it is therefore the website administrators who will view the RA certificate.  This RA certificate could be used for a HTTPS connection by a web front-end, or it could be used for some form of automated enrolment process, such as SCEP or ACME.

Of course, you could look at the name of the certificate issuer then visit their website to see if you can access the RA and thereby view the RA certificate.  But I'm sure you've got better things to do.

The Validation Authority (VA) may operate a CRL distribution point over HTTP, FTP, LDAP etc., or it may operate an OCSP service.  It is likely that a VA certificate (if used) would be visible to you when you (as the relying party) verifies a certificate.

You are more likely to see the VA's certificate on an OCSP response than a CRL distribution point as the latter tend to operate over non-TLS protocols.

> how can I document the X.509 record ?

I'm afraid I don't know what you mean.